# Eliminate menu collapse button on website

Tags: menus, buttons

I have a website I'm working on

```
sandyhookfoundation.com/wp.
```

It loads on desktop browsers with a "menu" button in the top left corner of the main menu. I can't seem to find how to eliminate it. I tried inspecting the code, and found the code that generates it, but I can't find the file that the code resides in.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that by add css script in you header.php file within the your wp-content>themes> folder.

```
<style>
  #navi-wrap .nav-toggle{
  display:none;
  }
</style>
```

If facing problem to do this, inform me please

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changes to `header.php` unless it is in child theme.

Comment: excellent, that worked great...i plan on setting up a chlid theme soon, thank you very much for your help

Comment: i noticed now that the menu collapses when the browser window is minimized, but it does not expand when you click on it...any way to fix this